# Why sometimes when watching a file/directory for changes it's not changing the flag to true?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

In the constructor i'm calling WatchDirectory method:

```
private void WatchDirectory()
        {
            FileSystemWatcher watcher = new FileSystemWatcher();
            watcher.Path = userVideosDirectory;
            watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastWrite | NotifyFilters.Size;
            watcher.Filter = "*.mp4";
            watcher.Changed += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);
            watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
        }
```

Then the event OnChanged:

```
private void OnChanged(object source, FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            var info = new FileInfo(e.FullPath);
            fileforupload = info.FullName;
            if (e.ChangeType == WatcherChangeTypes.Changed)
            {
                var theSize = info.Length;

                label2.BeginInvoke((Action)(() =>
                {
                    label2.Text = theSize.ToString();
                }));
            }
            dirchanged = true;
        } 
        catch (Exception ee)
        {
            string err = ee.ToString();
        }
    }
```

Then i'm using a while loop to check when dirchange flag is true:

```
                    WatchDirectory();
                    while (dirchanged == false)
                    {
                        if (dirchanged == true)
                        {
                            Youtube_Uploader youtubeupload = new 
                                            Youtube_Uploader(fileforupload);
                            break;
                        }
                    }
```

The problem is that sometimes it's never changes the `dirchanged` to `true` on the OnChanged event. Not sure why. It seems to fire the OnChanged event but sometimes it doesn't execute the `dirchanged = true;`

Therefore inside the `while` loop `dirchanged` flag remains `false` all the time.

I added now a new method i called it IsFileLocked:

```
protected virtual bool IsFileLocked(FileInfo file)
        {
            FileStream stream = null;

            try
            {
                stream = file.Open(FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.None);
            }
            catch (IOException)
            {
                return true;
            }
            finally
            {
                if (stream != null)
                    stream.Close();
            }
            return false;
        }
```

And i use this in the event OnChanged:

```
private void OnChanged(object source, FileSystemEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                var info = new FileInfo(e.FullPath);
                fileforupload = info.FullName;
                IsFileLocked(info);
                if (e.ChangeType == WatcherChangeTypes.Changed)
                {
                    var theSize = info.Length;

                    label2.BeginInvoke((Action)(() =>
                    {
                        label2.Text = theSize.ToString();
                    }));
                }
                dirchanged = true;
            }
            catch (Exception ee)
            {
                string err = ee.ToString();
            }
        }
```

And in the method IsFileLocked i'm getting exception:

The process cannot access the file 'C:\Users\bout0_000\Videos\My Great Game - My Great Capture - 2015-08-10 14-22-52.mp4' because it is being used by another process.

I'm using external program that create the file and since the program still working on creating the file the watcher can't get to it.
So i have a confilct here from one side i want to know to watch when the file is ready finished created but on the other side i can't know since the external program still working on it.

So how can i find out when the external program finished working on the file and the file is ready ?

This is the whole part of the code of the while:

```
if (request.QueryString[0] == "stop")
                    {
                        dirchanged = false; 
                        StartRecrod();                        
                        result = "Recording stopped and preparing the file to be shared on youtube";
                        WatchDirectory();
                        while (dirchanged == false)

                        {
                            if (dirchanged == true)
                            {
                                string ttttt = "ok";
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
```

I added a string ttttt just for testing.
Sometimes it's getting to the string ttttt when using a break point and sometimes not.

In my program when i touch my android screen it send command to the pc web server and it's getting here but someting is wrong with the while loop and the flag dirchanged sometimes it does enter the while and the IF and does the string ttttt and sometimes it dosen't.

This is what i did now with the await:

```
TaskCompletionSource<bool> sy;
        public async void SendResponse(HttpListenerRequest request)
        {
            string result = "";
            string key = request.QueryString.GetKey(0);
            if (key == "cmd")
            {
                if (request.QueryString[0] == "nothing")
                {
                    return "Connection Success";
                }
                if (request.QueryString[0] == "start")
                {
                    StartRecrod();
                    result = "Recording started";
                }

                if (request.QueryString[0] == "stop")
                {
                    dirchanged = false;
                    StartRecrod();
                    result = "Recording stopped and preparing the file to be shared on youtube";
                    sy = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();
                    WatchDirectory();
                    await sy.Task;
                    Youtube_Uploader youtubeupload = new Youtube_Uploader(fileforupload);


                }
            }
            else
            {
                result = "Nothing have been done";
            }
            if (Youtube_Uploader.fileuploadedsuccess != null && Youtube_Uploader.fileuploadedsuccess != "")
            {
                result = Youtube_Uploader.fileuploadedsuccess;
            }

            return result;
        }
```

But some problems.
First i'm getting errors over all the returns.

Error   2   Since 'Automatic_Record.Form1.SendResponse(System.Net.HttpListenerRequest)' returns void, a return keyword must not be followed by an object expression

And error when init my web server:

```
WebServer ws = new WebServer(SendResponse, "http://+:8098/");
```

On the SendResponse i'm getting:

Error   1   'void Automatic_Record.Form1.SendResponse(System.Net.HttpListenerRequest)' has the wrong return type

This errors happen now when changed the method to async.

This is my WebServer method that i get error when init it since it should get something else then async:

```
public WebServer(Func<HttpListenerRequest, string> method, params string[] prefixes)
            : this(prefixes, method) { }

        public void Run()
        {
            ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem((o) =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Webserver running...");
                try
                {
                    while (_listener.IsListening)
                    {
                        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem((c) =>
                        {
                            var ctx = c as HttpListenerContext;
                            try
                            {
                                string rstr = _responderMethod(ctx.Request);
                                System.Diagnostics.Trace.Write(ctx.Request.QueryString);
                                //ctx.Request.QueryString

                                byte[] buf = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(rstr);
                                ctx.Response.ContentLength64 = buf.Length;
                                ctx.Response.OutputStream.Write(buf, 0, buf.Length);
                                System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionStringBuilder builder = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionStringBuilder();

                            }
                            catch { } // suppress any exceptions
                            finally
                            {
                                // always close the stream
                                ctx.Response.OutputStream.Close();
                            }
                        }, _listener.GetContext());
                    }
                }
                catch { } // suppress any exceptions
            });
        }
```

Comment: Well, did you try to put a breakpoint in your exception catching? Because as it is now, you will never know if an exception is thrown, since you're just creating a new string but doing nothing with it.

Comment: I added new a new method IsFileLocked and using it in the OnChanged event i also updated my question with it. And i found that my watcher get conflict with the external program that create the file on hard disk. My main idea with the watcher is to check for file size changes and if no changes any more then the file is ready for upload. But the problem is that the watcher conflict since the external program is building the file.

Comment: How else can i tell if the file is ready ? I want to make that when the external program finished making the file it will be uploaded to youtube automatic. So i'm using the flag the while and the watcher but in some cases the watcher is conflicting with the external program.

Comment: Maybe the IsFileLocked method i'm using it wrong in the OnChanged ? Now i'm just calling it but maybe i should something else with that ?

Comment: Ok i changed the method to public async Task<string> so now two errors fixed but i'm still getting error in the constructor where i init my web server: WebServer ws = new WebServer(SendResponse, "http://+:8098/"); the error: Error 1 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task<string> Automatic_Record.Form1.SendResponse(System.Net.HttpListenerRequest)' has the wrong return type and this is the method WebServer: public WebServer(Func<HttpListenerRequest, string> method, params string[] prefixes) how can i fix this error ?

Comment: @Daniel: Instead of `await sy.Task;` you could do `sy.Task.Wait(timeout);` and then not need the `async` keyword.

Comment: Ben how do i know how much to wait ? (timeout)

Comment: And does the code after the wait is fine ? I mean after the waiting calling the   Youtube_Uploader youtubeupload = new Youtube_Uploader(fileforupload); is fine ? I mean once the waiting is over thats mean the file is ready ?

Comment: @DanielLip: How long to wait depends on how long your user is going to wait for their browser to update.  If the operation completes more quickly, you won't wait the full time.  Timeout is only for when the file watcher hasn't seen anything yet.

Comment: Ben sometimes i'm getting exception in the OnChanged method on the line:  sy.SetResult(true); the exception is: An attempt was made to transition a task to a final state when it had already completed. How can i solve it ?

Comment: After `sy.SetResult(true);` set `watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = false;`  This way you will not act on notifications more than once.

Answer (score 1):

This code is horribly broken.  Yes, `dirchanged` is always false inside the while loop, because if it becomes true you won't be in the while loop any longer.

In addition, your code blocks events from occurring, which may block the file watcher event itself, and also is not optimization safe.  Use proper synchronization, here's an example:

```
TaskCompletionSource<bool> sy;

private void OnChanged(object source, FileSystemEventArgs e)
{
    sy.SetResult(true);
}
```

and wait with

```
sy = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();
WatchDirectory();
await sy.Task; // or sy.Task.Wait()
```

(You'll need to use the `async` keyword on the method containing that code).

This fixes all the problems you had before -- it doesn't burn CPU cycles, it continues processing Windows messages, and it won't break if the compiler chooses to cache variables in registers.

Comment: Ben if you could show me the complete code how it should look like. Meanwhile i'm trying to do it on my own. Thank you.

Comment: Ben i also added to my question what i tried just now with the async. Not sure if what i did is the right code and also i'm getting some errors.

Answer (score 0):

`dirchanged` could be getting set to true just after evaluating the inner `if` block. Then, next loop it breaks out without ever running your uploader.

Answer (score 0):

So you have two main questions?

1.) Why is dirchanged not being set to true?

and the apparent cause...

2.) How do you use FileSystemWatcher to only act on a file that's available for edit?

FileSystemWatcher is known for being a little touchy, and I agree with your diagnosis that file access is probably the culprit. An unpredictable file access error is exactly what I would expected from a FileSystemWatcher trying to do something with a file that was just modified. Can you edit the code that's creating the file?  If so, one method I've used with FileSystemWatcher is to have it only watch for file creation of a fictitious file type such as "*.fsw".  The program creating the file will then rename it to "*.fsw" whenever it is done editing it, that way the FileSystemWatcher only gets called when it has a file available to act upon, and it can then rename the file to it's actual type.  Also, if you can edit the creation code, make sure that you are doing everything you can to release the file from there.  I've seen this behavior before because I forgot to close a TextWriter.

Also, I would move the line

```
 dirchanged = true;
```

Outside of the try statement.  Why have it in there since it definitely wont throw an error?  Also, your catch statement isn't really doing error handling. Any error in your try statement and you get ejected before reaching the dirchanged = true line without being alerted that this is what happened.  Have you tested your delegate code on its own? Is there a need to have the if statement for type = changed right there?  If you're troubleshooting, I would consider limiting your try statement content or moving it to after the while loop as much as possible.

Also, wouldn't this be a lot more simple for your while statement?

```
while (dirchanged == false){}
Youtube_Uploader youtubeupload = new Youtube_Uploader(fileforupload);
```

It's not the most elegant solution, but one work around is to simply wait if you know the program creating/editing the file is going to close it very soon...

```
while (dirchanged == false){}
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
Youtube_Uploader youtubeupload = new Youtube_Uploader(fileforupload);
```

EDIT: Better yet, rather than a while statement use Ben Voigt's suggestion of a TaskCompletionSource.  You'll still have to deal with the file being locked but you should be able to do that after the "task" has been flagged as completed.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't put my brackets on separate lines... the entire while loop exists in a single line in the code I gave.  The next line after it will only execute once the while loop breaks.  The while loop serves to pause the code while the condition is not met.

Comment: Dan but in my code look at my question i'm setting dirchanged to false before the while the init of dirchanged is false. So if you are doing while(dirchanged == false) it will enter inside without checking if dirchanged is true, that's why i did the watcher and the OnChanged event to change it to true when the file is not locked.  I found that doing while(true) and then inside checking if(direchanged == true) then inside using a break; this is working fine.

Comment: "while (dirchanged == false){}" Continuously evaluates the dirchanged value.  With what you have right now, the while statement will continue to loop very quickly.  If the dirchanged value get's set to true after the nested if statement evaluates, then the loop will not re-enter itself and the if statement will never be evaluated as true.  The symptom off this would be that you reach the "ttttt" line unpredictably, exactly as you've described.  Incidentally, this is one way to simulate randomness.